# Vuejs + Google Maps > document.getElementById and this.refs returning null for a div

Tags: google-maps, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to add google maps to my vuejs application following this tutorial here: https://markus.oberlehner.net/blog/using-the-google-maps-api-with-vue/

I have a div with id="maps" as well as ref="mapsection". I tried binding maps instance with the div with both document.getElementById as well as this.ref but I get the null/undefined error. Can someone please advise what I am doing wrong? I see the div created when I go I to inspect mode.

I have tried both of the following where "mapsection" is the ref and "map" is the id for the div.

`const map = new google.maps.Map(this.refs.mapsection);`

`const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'));`

View code:

```
      <el-row>
        <div ref="mapsection" id="map" style="width:100%;height:400px">

        </div>
      </el-row>
```

Script code:

```
 async mounted() {
      try {

        console.log(document.getElementById('map')); //returns null

        const google = await gmapsInit();
        const geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map')); //tried this.refs.mapsection as well.
        const locations = [{
                              position: {
                                lat: 48.160910,
                                lng: 16.383330
                              }
                            }]

        geocoder.geocode({ address: 'Austria' }, (results, status) => {
          if (status !== 'OK' || !results[0]) {
            throw new Error(status);
          }

          map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
          map.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.viewport);
          const markers = locations.map(x => new google.maps.Marker({ ...x, map }));
        });
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    }
```

Errors I am getting:

1. with `this.refs.mapsection` > `TypeError: Cannot read property 'mapsection' of undefined`
2. with `document.getElementById('maps')` > `TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The referenced tutorial does not use `el-row`.  Your problem has nothing to do with google maps.

To debug try **one** of these approaches.

1. put all of `mounted` in an async `$nextTick` to ensure render.
2. move your code out of el-row, el-table, etc, and into a div to isolate the issue.
3. `refs` in loops is often an `array`, so when you finally get this working, it is something to consider.

Comment: I separated the map into a separate components and imported it in the view, it worked.